# CAD model of the PR2?

Tags: ros, pr2, solidworks, cad, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone have a crude CAD model of the PR2? I'm designing a living lab and have done a few mockups in Solidworks. I would like to add the PR2 to get a feel for the size of the room.

UPDATE: I converted the pr2.urdf.xacro to a urdf file:

```
rosrun xacro xacro.py 'rospack find pr2_description'/robots/pr2.urdf.xacro > pr2.urdf
```

Next I converted it to dae file using the collada tool:

```
rosrun collada_urdf urdf_to_collada pr2.urdf pr2.dae
```

Using MeshLab I was able to save the dae file as a dxf file which I was able to open in SolidWorks.

However, it seems like the pieces were not moved to the correct locations and are all placed at the origin. Here is a screenshot: imgur.com/4UlQwVa.

Any idea on how to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63217/cad-model-of-the-pr2?/) by [sven-cremer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4951/sven-cremer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2013-05-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The PR2 meshes are likely defined with their origins at the various link origins.  When the URDF gets converted to a collada file, it's likely that the conversion tool does not account for kinematic positioning in the URDF, and instead just converts the individual mesh files.  This would result in a cluster of meshes all centered at the origin.

I don't have any suggestions for an "easy" conversion, but here's what I would do:

1. Extract each link/mesh as an individual part in Solidworks

- either by splitting parts out from the conversion you're already using
  - or converting the individual meshes referenced by @dornhege

1. Load up the PR2 in RViz, and position it in the pose you would like
2. Use `tf_echo` to get the transform from the base link to each individual link you have exported
3. Position the parts in Solidworks using the transforms from `tf_echo`

Like I said, this would likely be annoying and manual, but would probably work.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sven-cremer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4951/sven-cremer/) on 2013-05-23**:
Thanks, I will give it a try.

**Comment by [bbferko](https://answers.ros.org/users/15141/bbferko/) on 2014-04-23**:
Did anyone ever solve this issue? I would also need a full CAD model of the PR2.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-23**:
Sorry; the answer above is the current best solution; the CAD models of the PR2 have never been made public.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you don't need anything exact: The [pr2_description](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_description) package contains the PR2 meshes used in rviz.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2